# IDL Printf formatting

Tags: formatting, printf, idl

My intention is to write 2612 lines into a file containing 7 values, 6 of which have a label in increasing order from 1-6. The output has undesired additional spacing separating the values.

I am using:

for i=0,2611 do printf, 5, col13(i),' 1:',col1(i),' 2:',col2(i),' 3:',col3(i),' 4:',col4(i),' 5:',col5(i),' 6:',col6(i)

An example of the output I am getting:

```
 0.898083 1:      23.4910 2:      22.9830 3:      22.3010 4:      21.4080 5:      20.8960 6:      3.17989
```

desired output:

```
 0.898083 1:23.4910 2:22.9830 3:22.3010 4:21.4080 5:20.8960 6:3.17989
```

All insight is very much appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about the following?

```
IDL> print, randomu(seed, 6), format='(%"%f 1:%f 2:%f 3:%f 4:%f 5:%f")'
0.333924 1:0.478652 2:0.962699 3:0.827317 4:0.862164 5:0.465218
```

For your code, you could do something like:

```
format = '(%"%f 1:%f 2:%f 3:%f 4:%f 5:%f")'
for i = 0, 2611 do begin
  print, col13[i], col1[i], col2[i], col3[i], col4[i], col5[i], format=format
endfor
```